# How to load data to third dropdown with php and jQuery when the values of either the first or the second dropdown are changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The third dropdown is dependent on both the first and the second dropdown and different. I want to load data to the third dropdown when either the value of the first or the second is changed. My problem is the jQuery part not the php.

Thank you as you assist.

**MY HTML**

```
<select name="first" id="first">
 <option value="1">Item 1</option>
 <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>

<select name="second" id="second">
 <option value="1">Item 1</option>
 <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>

<select name="third" id="third">
 //load data when the values of either the first or the second dropdown are changed
</select>
```

**THE JQUERY I TRIED**

```
$(function(){
  $("#first").change(function() || $("#second").change(function(){
    $.post("third.php", {first: $("#first").val(), second: $("#second").val()}, function(data){
    $("#third").html(data);
    });
    return false; 
  });  
});
```

Comment: `$("#first").change(function() || $("#second").change(function()` - how is that even remotely supposed to make sense ... You probably just want `$('#first, #second').on(...)` ...?

Comment: [Plenty Examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+cascading+dropdown+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan, but this does not solve the problem, if I change another option in the second dropdown, fresh data will not be loaded until when I change the first dropdown. I want to avoid that. I want to load a fresh data if either of the dropdowns are changed.

Comment: @CBroe, with your suggestion, I have to change the first dropdown any time I change the second dropdown in order to load a fresh data in the third dropdown. I want to avoid that. I want to l load a fresh data in the third dropdown when either the  values of the first or the second dropdown is changed.

Comment: I have no idea what you are going on about here. `$('#first, #second').on('change', ...)` would execute the callback function each time the change event fires on _either_ of the selected elements.

Comment: @CBroe This is how i tried it$(function(){
  $("#first", "#second").on("change",function(){
    $.post("third.php", {first: $("#first").val(), second: $("#second").val()}, function(data){
    $("#third").html(data);
    });
    return false; 
  });  
});

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to put `return false` at the end there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delegate

```js
$(function() {
  $("#third").hide();
  $("#dropdowns").change(function() {
    $("#third").find('option').not(':first').remove();
    const first = $("#first").val();
    const second = $("#second").val();
    if (first !== "" && second !== "") {
      console.log(first,second)
      $.post("third.php", {
        first: first,
        second: second
      }, function(data) {
        $("#third")
          .append(data)
          .show();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdowns">
  <select name="first" id="first">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  </select>

  <select name="second" id="second">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  </select>

</div>
<select name="third" id="third">
  <option value="" disabled>Please select</option>
  //load data when the values of either the first or the second dropdown are changed
</select>
```

Comment: This solution has worked after some modification. However, I don't want to bring the third dropdown and place it in the same div with the first dropdown unless if there is no other options. I tried creating a class for both of them so that they can be left in that order, but it didn't work. Thank you

Comment: I do not understand your comment. I did not put the third dropdown in the same div

Comment: Thank you once again. I mean that i don't want to put the first and second dropdown in the same div because there is one dropdowns between the first and the second, I just removed it for simplicity. Your answer has solved the problem, I just changed the  id="dropdowns" to class="dropdowns" and it worked as I wanted. Answer accepted. $(function() {
   $(".dropdowns").change(function() {
     $.post("third.php", {
         first: $("#first").val(),
         session: $("#second").val()
       }, function(data) {
         $("#third").html(data);
       }); 
   });
});